# JavaScript not comparing properly

Tags: javascript

I have a program written in JS. It compares output of an function with number 4. However, it seems it cannot compare properly.

```
var myStringNotValidated =  "3T-4T";

var notValidate = myStringNotValidated.substring(3, 4);

if(notValidate === 4)
{
console.log("Value1");
}
else
{
console.log("null");
}
//OUTPUT IS NULL, WHICH IDEALLY SHOULD BE "Value1"
```

Can any one guide me where am I making mistake?

Comment: `notValidate` is **String**. `===` compares type too. Convert the string to number or compare it with string `'4'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Or compare with `==` so if one is a Number, both are coerced to Number for the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trapped in the same mistake which most JS developers do!

There is an difference between === and == in JS. ([Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)). Because of this, when you compare "4" with 4, it compares (String 4) with (Numeric 4), hence returning your else condition.

**Solution: Just replace === with ==**

```
var myStringNotValidated =  "3T-4T";
var notValidate = myStringNotValidated.substring(3, 4);
if(notValidate == 4)
{
console.log("Value1");
}
else
{
console.log("null");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pfrvn485/

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you want to check if notValidate is a **string**:

```
var myStringNotValidated =  "3T-4T";

var notValidate = myStringNotValidated.substring(3, 4);

if(notValidate === "4") // Change here
{
console.log("Value1");
}
else
{
console.log("null");
}
```

if you want to check if notValidate is a **number**, use **parseInt()**:

```
var myStringNotValidated =  "3T-4T";

var notValidate = parseInt(myStringNotValidated.substring(3, 4)); // Change here

if(notValidate === 4)
{
console.log("Value1");
}
else
{
console.log("null");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is wrong `if(notValidate === 4)` checks 4 as string.  either you can use `if(notValidate=='4')` or convert it to number & check.

Answer (score 1):

This is because === compares both value and type. In your program, noValidate contains a value of 4 but its type is string and you are comparing it with 4 whose type is number.

You can either use == or typecast noValidate to number.

```js
var myStringNotValidated =  "3T-4T";

var notValidate = Number(myStringNotValidated.substring(3, 4));
console.log(typeof notValidate);
if(notValidate === 4)
{
console.log("Value1");
}
else
{
console.log("null");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the string("4") with the int type(4). Need to be converted to an integer before comparing.

```
var myStringNotValidated =  "3T-4T";

var notValidate = parseInt(myStringNotValidated.substring(3, 4));

if(notValidate === 4)
{
console.log("Value1");
}
else
{
console.log("null");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var myStringNotValidated =  "3T-4T";

var notValidate = myStringNotValidated.substring(3, 4);

if(notValidate === "4")
{
console.log("Value1");
}
else
{
console.log("null");
}
```